# Datatable conditional rendering rows based on JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

In my JSON, I have one object `'Keys'` that contains an array

```
"keys": [
    {
        "key": "...",
        "customer": "...",
        "externalUser": null,
        "name": "Administrator key 1",
        "privileges": 32,
        "partitionKey": "...",
        "rowKey": "...",
        "timestamp": "2018-11-02T03:51:27.4099037+00:00",
        "eTag": "W/\"datetime'2018-11-02T03%3A51%3A27.4099037Z'\""
    },
    {
        "key": "...",
        "customer": "...",
        "externalUser": null,
        "name": "Administrator key 2",
        "privileges": 32,
        "partitionKey": "...",
        "rowKey": "...",
        "timestamp": "2018-11-02T03:51:27.4159094+00:00",
        "eTag": "W/\"datetime'2018-11-02T03%3A51%3A27.4159094Z'\""
    }
]
```

What I want to achieve is only display rows where `privileges` is equal to `'32'` on my table.

As of now, I got it to work using `rowCallback`

```
"rowCallback": function( row, data, index ) {
                if (data['privileges'] && data['privileges'] != '32') {
                    $(row).hide();
                }
            }
```

The complete function is here

```
function fetchKeysByCustomerId(customerId){
    var getKeysById = "https://..." + customerId;

        var tt = $('#apiAccessKeyTable').DataTable( {
            "ajax": {
                "url": getKeysById,
                "dataSrc": "keys"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": null },
                { "data": "name" },
                { "data": "key" },
                { "data": null },
                { "data": null }
            ],
            "columnDefs": [ 
                { "targets":0, "searchable": false, "orderable": false}          
            ],
            "order": [[ 1, 'desc' ]],
            'processing': true
        } );

        tt.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
            tt.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
                cell.innerHTML = i+1;
            } );
        } ).draw();
}
```

But this is not ideal because the rows were only hidden. Index column of the tables got messed up if I sort other columns.

How to completely remove or maybe only render rows with conditions?

Comment: Why can't you filter your dataset before setting it on your datatable?

Comment: Can you share your code where you are getting array and painting corresponding html?

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal Added the code above :)

Comment: @nbokmans I'm not sure how to filter the dataset while initializing datatable. Can you show me a quick example?

Comment: @jenna_3108 - There is an easy example available here -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168926/skipping-a-row-from-rendering-in-jquery-datatables